# Idiom for "don't put me with somebody together in the same sentence"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom used when people say that you are as good/bad as somebody, but you don't agree with it because you think you are not on the same level as them, or that you are way better than them.

Is there any idiom like "don't put me with somebody together in the same sentence"?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. When I was younger, I often heard *"Don't mention us both in the same sentence"*, although I can't find that on searching. Usually it was said of someone you didn't respect.

Comment: Surely there is an old saying to the effect of "I am unworthy to be mentioned in the same breath with X" (if the comparison is flattering) or "Don't yoke me to the same cart with that ass" (if the comparison is insulting).

Answer (score 10):

'Don't speak of me in the same breath as...'?  'Don't lump me in with..'?

Comment: +1 for don't lump me in with.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't tar me with the same brush](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tar_with_the_same_brush) is an idiom I might use in this case. I originally thought it was a seafaring allegory, but it looks like it might come from sheep farmers marking all the animals of their flock with tar.

Answer (score 0):

*Don't throw me and X in the same pot.*

*Don't bracket me with X*.

*X and I are not cast in the same mould.*

Answer (score -1):

To reject a favorable comparison with someone who is not up to your standards, you could say *Don't damn me with faint praise.*

This doesn't work with the rejection of a comparison that is negative. One approach some may take is to criticize the criticizer. *I've been insulted by better* [meaning I've been insulted by more important people than you, and I have survived it].

Comment: Is it disapproving to use the first one ? I mean does it sound arrogant when you say it ?

Comment: Probably anytime you say *I think I am better than that* it can sound arrogant.  It depends on the tone and the audience.

Answer (score -1):

Don't speak of my views with such **a broad brush**, or is nuance beyond you?

Answer (score -1):

May be this idiom is what you are looking for:

> Don't put everybody in the same boat.

It means: we are not in the same position, we are all different.

Comment: I agree with the Cambridge dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-the-same-boat "to be in the same *unpleasant* situation as other people:" -- The positive version is "to not be in the same league as someone".